# Sumifs with date difference in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with:

- list of recurrent expenses
  [image]
- other lists of recurring stuff, not important
- an estimation of inflow and outflow monthly
  [image]

The estimation is calculated with the following criteria (in AND logic):

1. date is between "since" and "to" (if since is empty, it is always valid, and the same for "to")
2. the month is a multiple of "every month" starting from "since", i.e. the voice must be included if "data" = "since" + "every months" * x, where x is an integer number

I wanted to create a sumifs like the following (Italian Excel, sorry):
=SOMMA.PIÙ.SE('Uscite'!$E$2:$E$1048576;'Uscite'!$C$2:$C$1048576;"<="&'v3'!$A2;'Uscite'!$D$2:$D$1048576;">="&'v3'!$A2;?????)

where ????? is the missing piece: I considered using a DATEDIF with "m", in order to get the difference in months between cell Ax and 'Uscite'!Since, then verifying if this difference is a perfect multiple of "every months", but no clue how to do it.
Any suggestion?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi Luca - is this actually Googlesheets? DATEDIF is a Google function.  If so, you need to retag the question as google-sheets.

Comment: Hello Mark, no it's Microsoft Excel. The 365 version has this hidden formula, I found out: it is not listed, but if you use it, it is recognized (I tried myself) - strange stuff...

Comment: Wow - that's super crazy. [It](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c) is for Lotus 123 compatibility, so it is really some dinosaur DNA. Good to know! Will use it as a party trick to impress my friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In english formulation, you could do:

```
=SUM( 'Entrate ricorrenti'!$E$2:$E$100 *
       ( ('Entrate ricorrenti'!$D$2:$D$100 >= 'v3'!A2) + ISBLANK('Entrate ricorrenti'!$D$2:$D$100) ) *
       IFERROR( MOD( DATEDIF( 'Entrate ricorrenti'!$C$2:$C$100, 'v3'!A2, "M" ), 'Entrate ricorrenti'!$B$2:$B$100 ) = 0,
                0 ) )
```

In Italian:

```
=SOMMA( 'Entrate ricorrenti'!$E$2:$E$100 *
       ( ('Entrate ricorrenti'!$D$2:$D$100 >= 'v3'!A2) + VAL.VUOTO('Entrate ricorrenti'!$D$2:$D$100) ) *
       SE.ERRORE( RESTO( DATA.DIFF( 'Entrate ricorrenti'!$C$2:$C$100; 'v3'!A2; "M" ); 'Entrate ricorrenti'!$B$2:$B$100 ) = 0;
                  0 ) )
```

So, this uses the very nice dinosaur function that you taught me about today. I have never seen this except for DAX.

It simply filters out the payments that stopped before the target date, **('v3'!A2)** by multiplying the payment values, `('Entrate ricorrenti'!$E$2:$E$100)`, times the boolean expression

`(('Entrate ricorrenti'!$D$2:$D$100 >= 'v3'!A2) + ISBLANK('Entrate ricorrenti'!$D$2:$D$100))`

that also checks to see if the To Date is blank.  Then it multiplies that times the modulo of the DATEDIF in months by the Frequency in months. If that is zero, then a payment lands in that month. **DATEDIF** has the nice property that if the date difference is negative, it generates an N/A error. This allows us to wrap it in an IFERROR to replace that with zero - this prevents the formula from including payments that have not yet started.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your feedback! I tried your formula on the inflow (entrate ricorrenti):

=SOMMA('Entrate ricorrenti'!$E$2:$E$1000000*('v3'!A2 >= 'Entrate ricorrenti'!$D$2:$D$1000000)*('v3'!A2<=DATA(ANNO('Entrate ricorrenti'!$D$2:$D$1000000)+(MESE('Entrate ricorrenti'!$D$2:$D$1000000)+'Entrate ricorrenti'!$C$2:$C$1000000)/12;RESTO(MESE('Entrate ricorrenti'!$D$2:$D$1000000)+'Entrate ricorrenti'!$C$2:$C$1000000-1;12)+1;1)))

it seems to use the end date as start date and not considering the monthly frequency as expected... I can share the document if necessary

Comment: @LucaColombo - It looks like I misunderstood the requirements. No need to send the XLS because I think this is only an issue with understanding what the output should be. Perhaps you can hand calculate of your cells above using your screenshot to make sure it is correct. In the meantime, I will change my answer based on my revised (and possible wrong) understanding.

Comment: thanks, I tried the new version and it correctly uses the data ranges (since-to) but it does not consider the expected frequency. If the "every month" column is set to 1, it must be calculated every month, but if the frequency is 12 it must be calculated only once in a year (for example, if a row starts from september 2019 and ends in september 2026 with a frequency of 12 months, it must be included only once a year, every september).
Harder and harder :)

Comment: Ahh ok - I was interpretting the frequency as a duration - I still don't have a clear understanding of the rules. Can you give an example of the correct answer for E2 in your screenshot above?

Comment: Of course, and i'm sorry for my bad explanation! Starting from my first screenshot:  
- xx1 should be included every July starting from 2019  
- xx2 every October from 2019  
- xx4 every 16 months from June 2020, so: June 2020, October 2021, February 2023 etc.  
- xx5 every month from December 2015  
    
So, in v3-E2 I should see xx2 + xx5 = 780€  
In June 2020, I will have xx4 + xx5 = 530€

Comment: @LucaColombo - ok, now I get the idea. Will take a minute to reformulate it into a revised answer.

Comment: @LucaColombo - ok, let's see if this did it. I ended up using DATEDIF, so your instinct was right. The trick to put a MOD (RESTO) into the Criteria. It is a lot easier to just use a SUM that multiplies all the booleans rather than SUMIFS in cases like this.

Comment: AMAZING man, it works exactly as expected! I have never used this approach to perform complex "sumifs" before, very very interesting. Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: @LucaColombo Cool! Well, I learned something valuable from you on DATEDIF. Without that function to get the difference in months, would be a much harder formula (tmk). As for the booleans, I find them a lot easier and more flexible because you can use both OR (as +) and AND (as *) in your logic which is harder in SUMIFS. Even applying Demorgan's Theorem, you can get stuck. Boolean arithmetic inside of SUM is a lot more flexible. It can work with MIN, MAX, AVERAGE... as well, but you need to embed it into an IF that is inside of the MIN or MAX...

Comment: +1 SUM and SUMPRODUCT give a lot of flexibility and power and the ability to compel booleans to 1s and 0s helps clean up the formulas. Replacing DATEDIF wouldn't have been that bad though: `Year2 * 12 + Month2 - Year1 * 12 - Month1` where Year2/Month2 use 'v3'!a2 and Year1/Month1 use 'Entrate ricorrenti'!$C$2:$C$100.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff - now that I have seen DATEDIF, I will never be able to unsee it. ;-) It is such a weird, throw-back function that somehow is there, but not there. It makes me wonder what other little easter-egg functions are out there. Occasionally, I will run across a spreadsheet with formulas that start with `=+`. Then you know the person who made it has grey hair.